# STM32G4x1 Changing polling rate of ADC

Tags: stm32

I am brand new with MCU and ADCs and would like to build my own oscilloscope. Right now I can capture signals at full speed (7.2 Msps) with the continuous setting and the DMA writes it directly to memory.

I was wondering if I would like to capture data at the ADC at variable rates (1 Msps, 25Ksps, etc) while the system is running, what ways could I achieve this? I am thinking of making the ADC into single-conversion instead, and just timing it accordingly, while the DMA automatically takes care of the writing. Is there a way where I could keep the ADC at continuous mode while only worrying about writing? Could I even change the ADC register **CONT** from continous to single and vice-versa while the system is on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is many ways to capture at variable rates.

Quote from the datasheet page that describes ADC features:

> Each ADC support multiple trigger inputs for synchronization with on-chip timers
> and external signals